# UIImagePickerController landscape mode shifts screen

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uiimagepickercontroller

I am trying to do a simple SwiftUI application that opens the camera or allows the user to pick a photo from the library. Currently, when I rotate the phone to landscape mode in the opened camera view, the whole interface shifts outside the screen for some reason.

The code that calls the UIImagePickerController:

```
struct CaptureImageView {
@Binding var isShown: Bool
@Binding var image: UIImage?
@Binding var sourceType: UIImagePickerController.SourceType
@Binding var imageSelected: Bool

func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
    return Coordinator(isShown: $isShown, image: $image, imageSelected: $imageSelected)
}}

extension CaptureImageView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<CaptureImageView>) -> UIImagePickerController {
    let picker = UIImagePickerController()
    picker.sourceType = sourceType
    picker.delegate = context.coordinator
    picker.allowsEditing = true
    picker.setEditing(true, animated: true)
    if (picker.sourceType == .camera) {
        picker.cameraCaptureMode = .photo
    }
    return picker
}

func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIImagePickerController,
                            context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<CaptureImageView>) {
    
}}
```

How it looks like when I rotate the screen:

[image: rotated screen]

Is there a proper way to make it adjust the view on orientation changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the only viable solution is portrait-locking the whole application.

Lesson learned: Swift-UI is absolute garbage.